# Function That Detects if Tweets are similar

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, nested-loops

I am trying to create a function in VBA that takes 2 strings and a threshold(a percentage in decimal form), and returns true if the strings contain a higher percentage of the same words than the threshold. 
Here is the code that I have so far...

```
Function isDup(tweet1 As String, tweet2 As String, threshold As Double) As Boolean
    'Declare variables to store words from each tweet
    Dim C1 As String
    Dim C2 As String

    'Use split function to split each tweet into single words. The " " is the delimiter, each space creates a new word
    C1 = Split(tweet1, " ")
    C2 = Split(tweet2, " ")

    'Loop through each word from tweet1 and each word from tweet2
    For i = LBound(C1) To UBound(C1)
        For j = LBound(C2) To UBound(C2)
            'Declare variable to store result from StrComp Function
            Dim Cresult As Double

            'Use StrComp Function to compare the current word from tweet1 to the current word from tweet2
            Cresult = StrComp(i, j, vbTextCompare)
        Next i
    Next j

    'Use If Then to return true if the tweets are more similar than the percentage given by the threshold
    If Cresult > threshold Then
    isDup = True

End Function
```

I am pretty new to VBA so there are some errors, specifically I keep running into the Expected: Array Error. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The value being stored inside of variable `Cresult` in your loop is reset every iteration. SO when you finally do you compare of `If Cresult > threshold Then` it's only comparing the last iteration in your loop.

Comment: Declare your arrays as `Variant` instead of `String`. You also iterate your `i` loop before iterating your inner `j` loop so that will throw an error as well unless fixed.

Comment: Your `StrComp` is comparing the loop variables `i` and `j`, which are just integers. Instead you want to compare the value stored in the array at the position of those loop variables like `StrComp(C1(i), C2(j), vbTextCompare)`

Comment: DIdn't you ask a similar question yesterday? (and also get an answer from Excel Hero, if I remember correctly)?

Comment: @JNevill - from what I understand `Dim` statements are not executed... so it's not true that it "redeclares."

Comment: @BigBen That's fair. I've put `dim` statements inside of loops and never suffered for it. It's just strange and wrong and I hate it.

Comment: @JNevill - what's more important to this question - I swear that it was asked (and answered by Excel Hero) yesterday :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick rewrite fixing up the things I noted in my comments above. If this isn't exactly what you were after, it should get you in the ballpark.

```
Function isDup(tweet1 As String, tweet2 As String, threshold As Double) As Boolean
    'Declare variables to store words from each tweet
    Dim C1 As Variant
    Dim C2 As Variant

    'Use split function to split each tweet into single words. The " " is the delimiter, each space creates a new word
    C1 = Split(tweet1, " ")
    C2 = Split(tweet2, " ")

    'Declare variable to store result from StrComp Function
    Dim Cresult As Double

    'Loop through each word from tweet1 and each word from tweet2
    For i = LBound(C1) To UBound(C1)
        For j = LBound(C2) To UBound(C2)

            'Use StrComp Function to compare the current word from tweet1 to the current word from tweet2
            If StrComp(C1(i), C2(j), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                Cresult = Cresult + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    'Use If Then to return true if the tweets are more similar than the percentage given by the threshold
    If Cresult > threshold Then
        isDup = True
    End If

End Function
```